# how to add one line in navigation

Tags: css, navigation, line

i have a little problem, i want to add a line that separates other tabs from last one, but i dunno how to do it, if you dont understand what im talking here is few pictures.

So, my page is responsive and i want that straight line to be visible only on desktop version of site(but that is not problem) so i added the background-image on whole nav div, and on my screen it looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EXBK.jpg .

but on some smaller or bigger desktop screens that line moves left or right depending on screen size so this is how it looks when the screen is little bit smaller : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3scG.jpg , so what i want? i want that one line to stay always the same in between of these nav bars!! so i get it that bg-image is not gonna work cause div is responsive but how can i stuck that line so it doesnt move nowhere? any help i would be verry grateful. Thanks :)

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML and CSS, preferably with a working example too, e.g. a JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Use `element:nth-last-child(1):before { ... }` to do it. Here's a fiddle example for you to review http://jsfiddle.net/xqv9jha0/

Comment: hey thanks guys, il try that one Chris thanks :) here is my code :

http://jsfiddle.net/7rgcmojx/ 
Thanks

Comment: @ChrisYongchu hi, i found your comment verry useful but now i have other problem, for :hover over nav-tab i have border-bottom, and now that border-bottom includes that "line" when i hover it, here's link of img : http://i.imgur.com/FVkHKhf.jpg :(( but thanks already for giving me some help,  i appreciate it :) ty :)

Comment: Is that "line" an image? If so, you can set the background to none on hover of the element. Like `element:hover { background: none; }`.

Comment: @K.Lu, I looked at your fiddle, you have the same `ID`s for our anchors. IDs need to be unique on the page. I recommend changing those to classes if you want to use the same value `navi`. Here's your revised fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7rgcmojx/1/

Comment: Another option is to remove your `border-bottom` and add `text-decoration` on `:hover` of the anchor links. That way it's only underlining the anchor. Here's a revised fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xqv9jha0/1/